# Getting value from HTML and inserting into PHP SQL to get data from database

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to get data from the database by using POST. In the example I want all the laptops from the database if 'storage' = 2GB

HTML:

```
<form action="getdata.php" method="POST">
<input type='hidden' name='storage' value='2GB'/> 
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM laptops WHERE storage=$_POST["storage"] ;";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row['id']. "<br>";            
        }
    }
?>
```

Somehow the `$_POST["storage"]='2GB'` part is not working out. I must be doing something wrong because the POST is working when I test it with the following: `echo $_POST["storage"];` which returns '2GB'.

Comment: You may need to escape the double quotation mark, this can be done in PHP as follows: `\” – To escape “ within double quoted string.`. I.e. your code would become `$sql = "SELECT * FROM laptops WHERE storrage=$_POST[\"storrage\"] ;";`. Read more on [Escape Characters in PHP](https://phppot.com/php/php-escape-sequences/)

Comment: That didn't work I'm afraid

Comment: Do you have any console errors? You can check this by hitting f12

Comment: No errors in the console. I've got logs and the logs are saying "mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\MAMP\htdocs\getdata.php on line 5" Line 5 is:     $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out I need to

```
include_once 'testing/databaseconn.php';
```

Where $conn is defined..................
Such a n00b, spend 1 hour on this

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your script is in a big risk for attacks, you need to validate and escape data before using in an SQL query, better yet, use prepared statements.

Now, your problem is that you're trying to include an array item inside a string and you must enclose it between curly brackets and enclose the value between single quotes.

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM laptops WHERE storage='{$_POST['storage']}' ;";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row['id']. "<br>";            
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I tried the following if everything is still working and it is:  $storrageResult = $_POST['storrage'];
 echo $storrageResult;

Comment: So after that I also tried WHERE ram=$storrageResult . No result